# Find & replace repeated characters in a string

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I wish to remove/replace " duplicate characters " inside a string, example >

Input,

```
staaacksoveerfloow
```

Desired output,

```
stacksoverflow
```

in this scenario `a` is repeated 3 times, `e` is 2 & `o` is 2. Rather than remove them entirely, we remove the duplicate/repeated entries.

However if the character isn't repeated before or after, we don't dedupe.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? The repeating characters could be any, or specific ones?

Comment: This sounds like an exercise, which you should at least attempt yourself. HINT: since you tagged your question `regular-expression`, you may wish to consider using a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to match repeated characters

Comment: ... alternatively, consider the `tr` command's `-s` option to squeeze repeats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ tr -s '[:lower:]' <<<"staaacksoveerfloow"
stacksoverflow
```

The `tr` utility is used here with its `-s` option to remove consecutive duplicates of any lowercase character in the given string.

In place of `[:lower:]`, you could use `a-z` or any range or character class that matches the characters that you want to affect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sed for that

```
echo staaacksoveerfloow | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\1\+/\1/g'
```

and I think the question is a dup―not dup state. you can refer more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368636/remove-repeating-and-control-characters-in-sed)

Answer (score 0):

In `ksh93`:

```
$ var=staaacksoveerfloow
$ print -r -- "${var//@(?)+(\1)/\1}"
stacksoverflow
```

(replace `?` with `[[:alpha:]]` / `[[:lower:]]`... if you want to restrict the deduplication to some class of characters only).

In `zsh`:

```
$ autoload -Uz regexp-replace
$ set -o rematchpcre
$ var=staaacksoveerfloow
$ regexp-replace var '(.)\1+' '$match[1]'
$ print -r -- $var
stacksoverflow
```

Again, replace `.` with `[[:alpha:]]` / `[[:lower:]]` (POSIX character classes), or the PCRE properties (like `\p{Latin}` to limit to letters in the Latin script (the one used in English) for instance), or `\w`... See `man pcrepattern` for details.